# Counter objects to Pandas DataFrame - only includes first case

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter

I am trying to convert a list of Counter objects into a Dataframe. 
Let's say i have the following Counter output:

```
Counter({''VERB': 19, 'PRON': 15, 'NOUN': 13, '.': 9, 'ADP': 9, 'DET': 7, 'ADJ': 4, 'PRT': 4, 'CONJ': 3, 'ADV': 3, 'NUM': 2, 'x': 0})
Counter({''VERB': 14, 'NOUN': 9, 'ADV': 8, 'PRON': 8, 'ADJ': 7, '.': 6, 'CONJ': 4, 'DET': 3, 'ADP': 3, 'PRT': 2, 'x': 0, 'NUM': 0})
```

I want to transform this into a pandas Dataframe. However, when trying to do this, it only includes the first Counter object, and thus not iterates over the other one (or the rest of the document with other counter objects).

```
index   NOUN    VERB    ADJ .   ADP PRON    DET CONJ    ADV PRT NUM x
0       13      19      4   9   9   15      7   3       3   4   2   0
```

Below you can find my used script. I guess i am missing a small detail but seems to miss it.

```
import nltk
import pandas as pd

for line in lines:
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens, tagset='universal')
    selective_tagged = ['ADJ','ADP','ADV','CONJ','DET','NOUN','NUM','PRT','PRON','VERB', '.', 'x']
    selective_tagged_words =[]
    for word,tag in tagged:
        if tag in selective_tagged:
            selective_tagged_words.append((word,tag))
    counts=Counter(tag for word,tag in selective_tagged_words)
    other_tags = set(selective_tagged)-set(counts)
    for i in other_tags:
        counts[i]=0
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(counts, orient='index').reset_index()   
    df = df.T 
    postag.append(counts)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: my suggestion would be to collect all the Counter dictionaries into a list and then read the list into pandas

Comment: I tried to do that using postag (which is a list including all the Counter objects), but then i would receive the following error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: run a test, after creating the counts variable, append it to postag ( i assume postag is declared somewhere as an empty list)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Stupid mistake from me, i placed the postag.append(counts) above df = pd.DataFrame(postag).reset_index() and it worked. Thanks!